# hasher not found

Tags: django, authentication, sha, pbkdf2

I'm trying to use different hashers with django 1.4. I have a hasher file 'hashers.py' in my app 'accounts',

```
import hashlib

from pbkdf2 import pbkdf2
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import SHA1PasswordHasher
from django.utils.crypto import pbkdf2


class SHA512PasswordHasher(SHA1PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "sha512"
```

and i added to settings,

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'accounts.hashers.SHA512PasswordHasher',
)
```

I get the following exception value,

Exception Value:

> hasher not found: accounts.hashers.SHA512PasswordHasher

also, if i don't have

> from pbkdf2 import pbkdf2

i get the following error,

> Exception Value:
>
> Unknown password hashing algorithm 'pbkdf2_sha256'. Did you specify it
>   in the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?

Even when i use any of the already written hashers in the main django library. Could be a bug?

Anyway, why is my new hasher not being found. I followed what is written in the django documentation.
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: Having the same issue. My hashers.py file gets compiled but then hasher not found. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For the settings, you should be adding your hasher to the list, not replacing it. So code it like this:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS += (
    'accounts.hashers.SHA512PasswordHasher',
)
```